PowerBI API Dataset Refresh 404 Not Found
I am currently using PowerShell to make an API call to refresh a dataset. Here is the code:
# Credentials
$AppId = "<AppId>"
$TenantId = "<TenantId>"
$ClientSecret = "<ClientSecret>" 

# Creating secure string & credential for Application ID and client secret
$PbiSecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $ClientSecret -Force -AsPlainText
$PbiCredential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($AppId, $PbiSecurePassword)

# Connect to the Power BI Service Account
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $PbiCredential

# Set the value of the Group ID and Dataset Name
$GroupId = '<GroupId>'
$DatasetName = '<DatasetName>'

# Get the Dataset ID of the Target Dataset
$Datasets = Get-PowerBIDataset -WorkspaceId $GroupId
$DatasetId = ($Datasets | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $DatasetName }).Id.Guid

Write-Host $DatasetId

# Refresh the Dataset
try {
    $Headers = Get-PowerBIAccessToken
    Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${GroupId}/datasets/${DatasetId}/refreshes" -Method 'Post' -Body ([pscustomobject]@{type='full'; commitMode='transactional'; applyRefreshPolicy='true'; notifyOption='MailOnCompletion'} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2 -Compress)
    Write-Output "Successfully triggered a PowerBI Dataset Refresh."
} catch {
    if ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ -eq 400) {
        Write-Output "A refresh is currently running."
        $RefreshStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${GroupId}/datasets/${DatasetId}/refreshes" -Method 'Get'
        
        $LatestRefresh = $RefreshStatus.value[0]
        $Status = $LatestRefresh.status
        $StartTime = $LatestRefresh.startTime
        $EndTime = $LatestRefresh.endTime
        
        $Output = @"
        Status: $Status
        Start Time: $StartTime
        End Time: $EndTime
"@
        Write-Output $Output

    } else {
        Write-Output "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

The script works as intended when running locally. If the dataset is not being refreshed currently then a refresh is triggered. If the dataset is currently being refreshed then the status is displayed. However, I am trying to deploy this to an automation software called ActiveBatch which allows you to schedule and trigger PowerShell jobs.
When I run the job on ActiveBatch, the job fails with a 404 Error. Specifically the following:

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

The service account has access to the dataset and there is no permissions issue. I saw a similar post regarding this which said that this is an issue related to AD group permissions. However, that is not the case here since the service account is added as an Admin to the dataset and the script works as intended locally.
What is strange is that the script works fine when I am running it on my laptop but it fails when running on ActiveBatch using the same service account credentials.
I tried hard coding the Group ID and the Dataset ID. I also ensured that the service account is indeed an admin on the dataset. I would expect the refresh to work on ActiveBatch given that it is working locally using the same service account credentials.

Do not get Authentication and Credentials confused.  This is a credential issue.  You are completing the connection from client to server, but the credentials that are being used do not have the permission to access the Route.  The client credentials get passed to the server and the client credentials are used to access the Route at the server.  if you are running the code on Client in a Service the Service has to be started with an Service Account.  A Service by default starts with a System Account that has no Environment (no user).  Create a Service Account of start Service with "As USER".
